# 7z zip several different folders

Tags: 7zip

I have following line to zip/backup my home folder

```
sudo 7z a -p /backups/`date "+%Y%m%d"`.backup.7z ~
```

Please advise how would I add another folder in the same line to be backed up?

Currently it is backing up my home folder `~`

I would like to add also `/etc/folder1` in the line.

Comment: Just a note: there's one directory in every (active) user's home directory that you don't want to back up, `~/.cache`, which true to its name contains automatically generated data (e. g. thumbnail lists or search indices) that will dimply be regenerated when it goes missing. On my system that's currently around 30 GB. See [What files and directories can be excluded from a backup of the home directory?](/q/40992/175814) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple that:

```bash
# note the space between '~' and '/etc/folder1'
sudo 7z a -p /backups/`date "+%Y%m%d"`.backup.7z ~ /etc/folder1
```

You can give more than one target to put into a 7z file by simply statig each path for its own, separated by a '' (space). Example for better reading:

```
7z a <archive-file> <path1> <path2> ... <path_n>
```

Note: You can avoid backticks in your command by using `$()`:

```
sudo 7z a -p "/backups/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).backup.7z" ~ /etc/folder1
```